# Circular reference using dependency inversion issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, es6-modules, circular-dependency

I have a circular reference issue using this pattern approach. `TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null` .

The strange thing is, if I move the `field.type.ts` in `src/constants.ts`, it doesn't throw an error and it works as expected, but crashes on the Unit Tests. If it leave the `fied.type.ts` contents in it's own file, it crashes.

Maybe I am not using/understanding this dependency inversion pattern the right way. I could probably fixed by passing the `FieldTypeToClassMapping` as a parameter in `Field.create(options: FieldOptions, fieldTypeMapping: FieldTypeToClassMapping)`, but I want to understand why this is happening.

```
import { StringField } from './string.field.model';
import { IntegerField } from './integer.field.model';
...

export const FieldTypeToClassMapping = {
  //Constructor of eg. StringField class so I can use `new FieldTypeToClassMapping[options.type](options)`;
  [FieldTypeEnum.STRING]: StringField,
  [FieldTypeEnum.INTEGER]: IntegerField,
};
```

```
//field/field.ts
import { FieldOptions } from 'src/interfaces/field.options.interface';
import { FieldTypeToClassMapping } from 'src/model/template/field.type.to.mapping.ts'

export abstract class Field {
  value: any;
  type: string;

  errors: string[] = [];

  public constructor(options: FieldOptions) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.type = options.type;
  }

  public static create(options: FieldOptions): any {
    try {
      return new FieldTypeToClassMapping[options.type](options);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid field type: ${options.type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

```
//field/integer.field.ts
import { FieldOptions } from 'src/interfaces/field.options.interface';
import { Field } from './field.model';

export class IntegerField extends Field {
  constructor(options: FieldOptions) {
    super(options);
  }
  protected validateValueDataType() {
    this.validateDataType(this.value, "value");
  }

  protected validateDefaultDataType() {
    this.validateDataType(this.defaultValue, "defaultValue");
  }
}
```

```
//field/service.ts
payload const postFields = [
  {
    type: "string", //FieldTypeEnum.STRING,
    value: 'a name'
  },
];

const postFields = [
  {
    type: "string",
    value: "John",
  },
  {
    type: "integer",
    value: 32,
  },
];


const fieldsArray = [];
postFields.forEach((item) => {
    const field: Field = Field.create(item);
    fieldsArray.addField(field);
  });

return fieldsArray;
```

Comment: Have each child class register itself in the `FieldTypeToClassMapping` instead of importing all the child classes in the same module that declares the parent class.

Comment: Yes, this is a circular module dependency problem, so please [edit] your question to show the module `import` statements in your code

Comment: Which module system are you using? Do you compile TypeScript to ES6 modules or to CommonJS?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for the late reply. I have added the imports for context. Also, CommonJS. In the meanwhile I fixed it by passing the `FieldTypeToClassMapping` as a parameter in the `create()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create(options: FieldOptions)` function is defined inside the class `Field`, but then it tries to instantiate an instance of a class that extends `Field`.

I think that is where the problem arises. I don't know the entire contents of your files, but I imagine that at the top of any `field.type.ts` file you import `Field`. However since `Field` can instantiate any concrete implementation of itself it would need to know about them so you would need to import everything that extends `Field` inside `Field`.

I don't know/understand the dependency inversion pattern well enough to relate it to your question. But given the provided information, perhaps a **Factory Pattern** is what you need?

You could move the the function `create(options: FieldOptions)` to a `FieldFactory` class. Your create function is practically a factory function already.

Comment: Yes, my thought where the same. The mind bending thing was, it didn't crash when I've put the `FieldTypeToClassMapping` in an existing file `constants.ts`, which was only temporary. After moving it to a different file, crashed. Moved it back, worked. I was thinking I missed something and was curious of what.
Did the usual, rebuild, deleted dist, etc. Same behaviour. Really strange.
I guess I'll try the factory pattern on the next refactoring.